# shared ViewBag data with different action in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
   public ActionResult Completed()
    {
       ViewBag.PersonalInfo="";
       ViewBag.Experience="";
        ViewBag.Work="";
    }

   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Publication(MainPageModel obj)
    {
        ViewBag.PersonalInfo="";
        ViewBag.Experience="";
        ViewBag.Work="";
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Publication(MainPageModel obj)
    {
        ViewBag.PersonalInfo="";
       ViewBag.Experience="";
        ViewBag.Work="";
    }
```

I used this ViewBag with this three action but I want to used like method 
 like

```
   public void methodname()
   {
    ViewBag.PersonalInfo="";
       ViewBag.Experience="";
        ViewBag.Work="";
    }
```

and call in different action `methodname()`

how to do it MVC4?

Is it possible to write like method ?

Comment: can you please confirm different controller or different actions?

Comment: Sorry but I am looking  for different action in same controller

Comment: yup you can then call your methodname in every action. The downside of this is if you are making a database call, then your db will be hit everytime and even if you cache the values. Viewbag are by the way considered anti MVC as they save state, and signal bad design

Comment: Jack M  ok , May I request then what is best way please give example